# Merge 2 relations on OR instead of AND

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have these two pieces of code that each return a relation inside the Micropost model.

```
scope :including_replies, lambda { |user| where("microposts.in_reply_to = ?", user.id)}

def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
  followed_user_ids = user.followed_user_ids
  where("user_id IN (?) OR user_id = ?", followed_user_ids, user)
end
```

When I run `r1 = Micropost.including_replies(user)` I get a relation with two results with the following SQL:

```
SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` WHERE (microposts.in_reply_to = 102) ORDER BY 
microposts.created_at DESC
```

When I run `r2 = Micropost.from_users_followed_by(user)` I get a relation with one result with the following SQL:

```
SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` WHERE (user_id IN (NULL) OR user_id = 102) ORDER 
BY microposts.created_at DESC
```

Now when I merge the relations like so `r3 = r1.merge(r2)` I got zero results but was expecting three.  The reason for this is that the SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` WHERE (microposts.in_reply_to = 102) AND 
(user_id IN (NULL) OR user_id = 102) ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC
```

Now what I need is `(microposts.in_reply_to = 102) OR (user_id IN (NULL) OR user_id = 102)`
I need an `OR` instead of an `AND` in the merged relation.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly with Rails. Rails does not expose any way to merge ActiveRelation (scoped) objects with `OR`. The reason is that ActiveRelation may contain not only conditions (what is described in the `WHERE` clause), but also joins and other SQL clauses for which merging with `OR` is not well-defined.

You can do this either with Arel directly (which ActiveRelation is built on top of), or you can use [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel/), which exposes Arel functionality through a DSL (which may be more convenient). With Squeel, it is still relevant that ActiveRelations cannot be merged. However Squeel also provides [Sifters](https://github.com/ernie/squeel/#sifters), which represent conditions (without any other SQL clauses), which you can use. It would involve rewriting the scopes as sifters though.